# Find a repeating pattern in a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to clean strings from their longest repeating pattern.

I have a list of approximately 1000 web pages titles, and they all share a common suffix, which is the name of the website.

They follow this pattern:

```
['art gallery - museum and visits | expand knowledge',
 'lasergame - entertainment | expand knowledge',
 'coffee shop - confort and food | expand knowledge',
 ...
]
```

How could I automatically strip all strings from their common suffix `" | expand knowledge"`
?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Sorry, I did not make myself clear enough. 
I have no information about the `" | expand knowledge"` suffix in advance. 
I want to be able to clear a list of strings of a potential common suffix, even if I do not know what it is.

Comment: can you expand on your requirements a little bit. Right now it appears as though you're asking for something that will take some insane computational time.

Comment: @SamIam I'm working on a crawler needed minimal knowledge on the HTML structure of the target website. I'm scraping the title of a page from the <title> HTML tag. All the pages of this website contains a common pattern (`` | expand knowledge``), which I would very much like to get rid of, to avoid any redundancy.
The main problem is that I have no nformation about the suffix in advance, as the crawler would be released on several websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [`os.path.commonprefix`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) function on the reversed titles:

```
titles = ['art gallery - museum and visits | expand knowledge',
 'lasergame - entertainment | expand knowledge',
 'coffee shop - confort and food | expand knowledge',
]

# Find the longest common suffix by reversing the strings and using a 
# library function to find the common "prefix".
common_suffix = os.path.commonprefix([title[::-1] for title in titles])[::-1]

# Strips all titles from the number of characters in the common suffix.
stripped_titles = [title[:-len(common_suffix)] for title in titles]
```

Result:

> ['art gallery - museum and visits', 'lasergame - entertainment',
>   'coffee shop - confort and food']

Because it finds the common suffix by itself, it should work on any group of titles, even if you don't know the suffix.

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol Be wary, that if coincidentally, the last letters in every entry is the same, this will also return that last letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually know the suffix you want to strip, you could simply do:

```
suffix = " | expand knowledge"

your_list = ['art gallery - museum and visits | expand knowledge',
 'lasergame - entertainment | expand knowledge',
 'coffee shop - confort and food | expand knowledge',
...]

new_list = [name.rstrip(suffix) for name in your_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that all strings have the common suffix, then this will do the trick:

```
strings = [
  'art gallery - museum and visits | expand knowledge',
  'lasergame - entertainment | expand knowledge']
suffixlen = len(" | expand knowledge")
print [s[:-suffixlen] for s in strings]
```

output:

```
['art gallery - museum and visits', 'lasergame - entertainment']
```