# How to find repeating individual strings in a list?

Tags: python, associations, data-mining

I tried this solution: [Find a repeating pattern in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461398/find-a-repeating-pattern-in-a-list-of-strings). But it did not work from my list format. I did not get any errors but it was displaying wrong answers. I used the same code and I used dict to store all the lists with a key:

```
common_suffix = os.path.commonprefix([listDict[::-1] for items in listDict])[::-1]
stripped_titles = [items[:-len(common_suffix)] for items in listDict]
print len(stripped_titles)
```

The answer I get is 0.

Here are the lists. I have already created these lists from a CSV file data:

```
list1 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c4', 'y7', 'u5']
list2 = ['b4', 't5', 'g1']
list3 = ['b2', 'c4', 'f6', 'a1']
list4 = ['b2', 'a1']
list5 = ['r4', 'c4', 'a1', 'b2']
```

Here I want to find the repeating strings. Lets say, I want to take three elements `a1, b2, c4` (from list1) an I want to find how many times these three strings exists in other lists. Order does not matter. String items should be in other lists. In this case, `a1, b2, c4` exists in list1, list3, and list5. So I want the answer to be "first three elements of list1 are repeated 3 other lists".

How can this be done with the following feature: I want to be able to pick a number, lets say `k = 3`, then the FIRST THREE element of all the lists will be tested for repeating patterns and the output will be,

```
a1, b2, c4 = 3
```

and so on.

Comment: What were the errors that you were getting?

Comment: Show your code. And use `print` to see values in variables to check whether script does what you expect in any part of code.

Comment: how to you get `b4, t5, g1 = 5`? I dont see them in any other lists.

Comment: @Gabriel that was just for an example

Comment: @furas I added the code. I am sure it is wrong and that is why looking for help.

Comment: A good example should be consistent. When your example output doesn't match your example input, people just get confused.

Comment: Same order? Same position in the lists? Your example is not consistent with your description

Comment: @dawg not the same order. Just the strings should be in the other lists. but k = 3 should pick the first three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are after (count each list where all the items appear including in the first), you can do:

```
lists=[ ['a1', 'b2', 'c4', 'y7', 'u5'],
        ['b4', 't5', 'g1'],
        ['b2', 'c4', 'f6', 'a1'],
        ['b2', 'a1'],
        ['r4', 'c4', 'a1', 'b2']]

k=3
tgt=tuple(lists[0][0:k])
di={tgt:1}
for li in lists[1:]:
    if all(e in li for e in tgt):
        di[tgt]+=1

print(di)
```

Prints:

```
{('a1', 'b2', 'c4'): 3}
```

If you want to simplify to a single line:

```
di={tgt:sum(all(e in li for e in tgt) for li in lists)}
```

Then if you want your exact output:

```
>>> print '{}={}'.format(', '.join(tgt), di[tgt])
a1, b2, c4=3
```

Comment: it should be all three must be available together.

Comment: @Gworld: If I understand what you want, fixed.

Comment: this is excellent. Accomplished, what I exactly wanted... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand the question, you are asking the following: Given a set of strings, return the number of lists that any of these strings appear in.

So for `list4` and `k=2` we have `'b2'` and `'a1'`.  Both appear in `list1` so we get one list.  Neither appear in `list2` so that doesn't add 1.  They both appear in `list3` and `list5` which makes 3 lists in total (excluding the original `list4`).  However, my solution would also add a list if it contained only one of `'b2'` or `'a1'`.

First is a solution with a list of lists then one with a dict of lists.

```
list1 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c4', 'y7', 'u5']
list2 = ['b4', 't5', 'g1']
list3 = ['b2', 'c4', 'f6', 'a1']
list4 = ['b2', 'a1']
list5 = ['r4', 'c4', 'a1', 'b2']
```

Here I've packaged your lists into a list of lists.

```
lall= [list1,list2,list3,list4,list5]

def cmatch1( lall, l0, k ):
    """ lall: a list of lists
        l0: the list to check
        k: number of entries from beginning of l0 to look for
    """
    m = 0
    for li in lall:
        # dont check against supplied list
        if li is l0:
            continue
        # loop over first k entries in supplied list
        for cn in l0[:k]:
            # if any of them appear in another list increment and break out
            if cn in li:
                m += 1
                break
    return m
```

If instead you have a dict of lists,

```
dl = {'list1':list1, 'list2':list2, 'list3':list3, 'list4':list4, 'list5':list5}

def cmatch2( dl, key, k ):
    """ dl: a dict of lists
        key: key of list to check
        k: number of entries from beginning of dl[key] to look for
    """
    m = 0
    for ki,li in dl.items():
        # dont check against supplied list
        if ki == key:
            continue
        # loop over first k entries in supplied list
        for cn in dl[key][:k]:
            # if any of them appear in another list increment and break out
            if cn in li:
                m += 1
                break
    return m
```

If you want to then check the first three entries in each list against every other list you can call the above functions indicating each list once using the second argument.  Not sure what you want to happen when `k=3` and `list4` doesn't have `k` entries but you can check for that in the outer loop over lists.

So if you do,

```
>>> cmatch2( dl, 'list1', 3 )
3

>>> cmatch2( dl, 'list2', 3 )
0

>>> cmatch3( dl, 'list3', 2 )
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_common(k,l):
    c = Counter()
    for ele in l:
        c.update(ele[:k])
    most_com = c.most_common()
    final = [x for x in c if c[x] == most_com[0][1]]+[most_com[0][1]]
    return final
print find_common(3,lists)
['a1', 'b2', 'c4', 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If order information is not that important, have a look at [PyFIM](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html), which implements numerous algorithms for **frequent itemset mining**. These methods will traditionally sort your data items.

There is also a version of this problem known as "**frequent subsequence mining**", which takes order into account.